# Resizing a <div> container inline?

Tags: html, css, wiki

So, I'm on a  wiki, and I'm putting a personal image on. In order to not waste space and possibly risk image policy, I am uploading the image to Imgur and using HTML to put it in my Userspace using this code:

```
<div style="text-align:left" alt="Chronoculars">https://i.imgur.com/0iTLJ3O.png</div>
```

However, the file I uploaded is too hi-res, and it displays too large when put on the webpage. I have found several fixes to the problem, but they all require external CSS, which I cannot do because this is all on a wiki.

Can I resize the image inline?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="text-align:left;" alt="Chronoculars"><img style="height:500px; width:500px;" src="https://i.imgur.com/0iTLJ3O.png"></div>
```

Comment: Doesn't work.  The text below the image moves up as if it was resizing, but the image is remaining the original size.

Comment: Now it just completely ignores all of the HTML code. Never mind all this mess, I'm just gonna reupload it smaller. Thanks for your help, anyhow!